# How can I delete an specific row and column in a list?

Tags: python, list

I need some tips. I have a square list "y" ("y" has a nxn size). This is an example:

```
y=[[20,30,35,40],
   [10,25,55,45],
   [15,39,19,59],
   [25,35,24,17]]
```

I have another list "x"("x" has a nx2 size).This is an example:

```
x=[[1,1]
   [2,0]
   [3,0]
   [4,1]]
```

I want to find in the list "x"(for each row) if appears (in the second column of the list "x") the number "1". If the number "1" appears in the second column of the list "x", I want to delete the respective row and the respective column in the list "y". In the example above, in the list "x" the number "1" appears in the first row and the four row of the list "x". Then I need to delete the respective rows and columns in the list "y".

When "1" appears in the first row in the list "x" (for the example above), this is the desired list "y"(I need delete the first row and delete the first column in the original list "y"):

```
   y=[[25,55,45],
       39,19,59],
       35,24,17]]
```

Then, because "1" appears in the third row in the list "x"(for the example above), this is the desired list "y"( I need delete the third row and delete the third column in the original list "y"):

```
  y=[ [25,45]
      [35,17]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see "1" in the third row of "x".

Comment: This is a "can you help me fix my homework solution" site, not a "can you do my homework for me" site

Comment: Perhaps you can begin by writing a function to delete specific rows and columns from the array. Something like `remove(y,i,j)` to be called like `y = remove(y,i,j)`. Once you have that written and debugged, figure out how to loop over `x`, calling `remove` with the right arguments when you encounter a 1 in the second column. Also, things really go better on Stack Overflow if you do show some code and ask for help, rather than simply stating your specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The function

```
def remove(a,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for k,row in enumerate(a) if k != i]
```

answers your stated question ("how can I delete a specific row and column from a list"), though it is still obscure exactly which rows and columns you want to remove.

In the case of your `y`, the two lines

```
>>> y = remove(y,0,0)
>>> y = remove(y,1,1)
```

results in

```
>>> y
[[25, 45], [35, 17]]
```

You just need to figure out how to iterate through `x` and calculate the needed indices (`0` and `1` in this case).